# How to create dynamic nested divs within ul li tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create dynamic nested divs within a ul li. This is what I need to creat dynamically.

```
<ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="videoThumbnail">
                                        <img src="./img6.jpg" />
                                        <div class="videoDesc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
                                        <div class="videoDate">02/07/2012</div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>..
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you please try to put some more effort in explaining what you want with some more details? It's hard to guess what your problem is... I'd like to help you out.

Comment: You have given us the output code, but we know absolutely nothing about what you have from before and how to access that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, give the ui a id, i choose `rootEl`

```
<ui id="rootEl">
</ui>
```

Second, this JavaScript:

```
var rootEl = document.getElementById('rootEl');

function appendStuff() {
    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
    var videoThumbnail = document.createElement('div');
    var myImage = document.createElement('img');
    var videoDesc = document.createElement('div');
    var videoDate = document.createElement('div');
    videoThumbnail.setAttribute('class','videoThumbnail');
    myImage.src = "./img6.jpg";
    videoDesc.setAttribute('class','videoDesc');
    videoDate.setAttribute('class','videoDate');
    videoDesc.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    videoDate.innerHTML = "02/07/2012";

    videoThumbnail.appendChild(myImage);
    videoThumbnail.appendChild(videoDesc);
    videoThumbnail.appendChild(videoDate);
    listItem.appendChild(videoThumbnail);

    rootEl.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

finally, a button to create that stuff and append it

```
<button onclick="appendStuff()">click me</button>
```

Now, every time you click that Button, you will append that stuff, if you doesnt want to have it multiple times you can modify my function to display other data or just make the button invisible or disable it **I please you to ask google before you ask here**.